# How to ensure azure DevOps pipelines agents are malware protected?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, documentation, agent

As I am using Azure Pipelines for building my project on agents managed by Microsoft.
And now I want to make sure these agents are malware protected.

I assume they are already malware protected, as Microsoft manages them.

But I am looking for "**Evidence**" to support my assumption.

Any documentation link or some way to get evidence

Comment: Did you look at the agent documentation? Microsoft explains how the agents are built, run, and sandboxed.

Comment: No, can you please help me with the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably look at the security section for the [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#security

Comment: Even though this doesn't provide me evidence that it's malware protected.
It helped me to understand that they are not malware protected. and need to use CIS hardened images in self hosted agents to make it more secure.